# How to put characters from data file into an array

Tags: python, arrays

i have a datafile (dimension: n x m) containing only characters. What is an easy way to put them into a two dimensional char array in phyton?

the data in the file could look like this:

```
#####
#.x.#
#..y#
#####
```

Comment: which part of this is the issue?

Comment: @njzk2 most people who ask something like this probably don't recognize that there are "parts of" it.

Comment: Boo, hiss re: "one-liner" request. Stack Overflow is narrowly focused on _practical_ problems (see first line of second paragraph of https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask); sacrificing readability/maintainability/robustness for terseness is inherently impractical.

Comment: Also, quite separate from my personal vendetta against people asking for one-liners, it's not kosher to edit a question in such a way as to invalidate prior answers after that question has been answered. (Invalidating _comments_ is okay; invalidating _answers_ is not).

Comment: sorry, stackoverflow recommended me to change my question, didnt know, taht the answers were not deleted :-(  sorry again!

Answer (score 1):

- Read the file and determine the dimensions `nxm`.
- create `numpy` array of that dimension and specify `dtype='U1'` it will ensure ensure that each element in the numpy array can hold a `single` character from the data file.

```
import numpy as np

# Read the data file and store its contents in a list
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]

#dimensions of the data file
n = len(lines)
m = len(lines[0])

#Create an empty numpy array of characters with the desired dimensions
char_array = np.empty((n, m), dtype='U1')

#Iterate over each line and each character in the line, and assign the characters to the numpy array
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        char_array[i, j] = lines[i][j]

print(char_array)
```

Output-

```
[['#' '#' '#' '#' '#']
 ['#' '.' 'x' '.' '#']
 ['#' '.' '.' 'y' '#']
 ['#' '#' '#' '#' '#']]
```

Comment: THANk YOU - this really helped me and i got exactly what i wanted! 
i now was recommended to change my question as this was answered several times before... so now I only would like to know, if this can be done in ONE LINE in python :-)

Answer (score -1):

if i understand what you are talking about then you can open and read the file, then parse each line of the file to create rows of characters. finally you could try and store these rows in a two-dimensional char array.
for example:

```
file_path = "your_file.txt"
char_array = []

with open(file_path, "r") as file:
  for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    row = list(line)
    char_array.append(row)
```

You can access specific characters using indices like `char_array[row][column]`

Comment: (1) Arrays and lists are not the same thing. Use proper terminology (especially when answering to an inexperienced programmer). (2) You don't need to append every line to a list: just read the file as a list of lines. This may also be an opportunity to introduce the author of the question to list comprehensions. (4) Good idea for `with`/`as`. (5) Good idea for `list(string)` to transform a string into a list of characters.

Comment: To add to the comment by #Arseni Mourzenko Python Lists do not have rows and columns. You are creating and then accessing a List of Lists using the appropriate indices.

Comment: @ArseniMourzenko OP used the "array" terminology first, and probably also didn't mean that (Numpy arrays generally don't make sense for holding text). If this question weren't about a routine combination of tasks, then that part should have been clarified before anyone wrote any answers. But with the natural inference that OP wants a list of lists (and says "array" due to a lack of familiarity with Python's built-in data types), there are basically two things that need to be understood, both of which are extremely thoroughly answered already.